# Dynamics Ax Label not updating

Tags: axapta, label, dynamics-ax-2012

I just edited a label using the label editor in Dynamics Ax and it was not changed everywhere. Some Forms have taken the change and some haven't.

To be more precise, I modified the label: Responsible Employee in the case management. The name was changed in the big form where all the Cases are listed (Here the label change worked) but if I click on a single case to view the details, the old name still appears and I triple checked, it is the same label and there is no label with the old name in the labels list.

Anyone got an idea? I could try to recompile the CIL but I cant believe that for something this simple I have to run the compiler for hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing an existing label I always restart the AOS(s) to ensure that the change takes place. I've noticed that the labels don't get written to the .ald-files until the AOS gets shut down, which would explain why it's not visible if you have several AOSs or there is some caching of labels.

Comment: This seemed to be the issue. Sorry for late response approval. And thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have changed the same language as the one on your user setting (en-us or en-uk)?

Do you have multiple AOS instances? If so restart the (other) AOS.

Also have you made a new label and updated the corresponding element? There might be other uses of the old label.

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting the .ali file from the Application file system. 
usually located under C:/program file/dynamics ax/50(if is ax 2009)/application/appl// 
try to find the .ali file with the same name of label file id(eg: axPQRen-us.ali, where PQR is the label file) and along with language.
after deleting the .ali file restart the aos and this should automatically create the ali file with the recent changes.
Also make sure that the label of the control of big form and the cases(where you fnd the difference) control are derived from te same labelid.